# Transparent checkbox with theme-support?

Tags: delphi, transparent, tcheckbox

I'm looking for a simple, transparent checkbox component that properly supports XP/Vista/7 theming.

It should also work with Delphi 7.

I've found a component on Torry's that's not working properly, and I know that Raize components has a transparent checkbox - but I'm obviously not going to pay $300 for the entire package just to get this single component.

I've also found many other solutions, but none of them support theming.

The main problem is that TCustomCheckBox is a TWinControl descendant, and in order to implement transparency, you need to make a new TGraphic descendant control from ground up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LMD-Tools SE is free, works great on Delphi 7 and has a checkbox component that has a transparency property.  I've recently used TLMDCheckbox with its transparency property enabled with Delphi 7.

http://www.lmdinnovative.com/download/index.php#LMD

Download file: setupse10d7.zip.  Sorry, I can't post the whole path (url) since I don't have enough juice yet.

This should fix you up :).

ShawnH.

Comment: Thank you, this is the best solution so far.
But I'm out of luck. It's working nice on TImages and TShapes, but I'm using a third party control (it produces a good looking gradient and is called TManyShape) as a background of the checkbox. LMDCheckbox doesn't support this component, must be the way TManyShape draws itself :-(

Answer (score 0):

Raize Components is overkill for just this component, but much more capable and supports transparency in a whole load more components. Once you have it, you'll appreciate the other items greatly. I'd say it is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: If Raize was selling their components separately, I'd be willing to pay $50 to get just this one.

But since my program is already complete in its own, and I just need the checkbox, this is not a viable option.

Comment: Raize Components adds so much more design time experience for standard components. Even when you use none of the Raize components, it pays for itself :-)

Comment: Guys are you getting paid for this by Raize? No way I'm going to pay hundreds of dollars for something I won't use. (My app is ready, I just need this darn checkbox to get fixed)

Comment: @Steve Yes, I understand that, but you will get a load of useful functions and classes too. Of course it is too expensive for one component, but consider it an investment. 8-) I know how much pain Ray went through to support transparency properly, and it would cost more than the components to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept an alternative control there is JvXPCheckCtrls.pas with its TJvXPCheckbox component in the JVCL library. http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org
I think (if I remember correct) it is transparent when themes are used.

It's quite a large package which will add to vcl with the installation of Jvcl. And it doesn't cost you a cent.

But remember, the TJvXPCheckbox component is part of their XP-controls package and you cannot simply lift out the component as a standalone. You will need the installation of Jedi and to get the core code and necessary theme handling to use it. 
- Its Mozilla Public Licence ("MPL") version 1.1.

Comment: I've tried this component a while back but it didn't work out. If I remember correctly, it supported skinning (it had office style look, etc.) but not OS-level theming.

Answer (score 0):

I use AlphaControls for some of my programs - all of their components are skinnable and have reasonably powerful graphics handling options.  A lot of the components also have more features than their corresponding Delphi standard components - some I just use for those functions alone.  There's a free Lite version available at www.alphaskins.com - it may just be what you're after.  It's not Vista/7 theme-aware, mind you.  We use Delphi 2010 and vista/7 theme awareness is built into the standard VCL there, although that's probably not the solution you were hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I ran into what I think is the same problem when working with the TMSSmooth controls:  the label of a checkbox place on a form looked terrible because it was not transparent.

Their demo/example programs had nice looking checkboxes so I took a look at their sample code.

Turns out they reduced the width of the checkbox component to 13 so that *only the box itself* and no caption shows. Then they added a TLabel for the caption.

Seemed like a clever workaround to me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but TLabels can't have focus. When you tab to a checkbox, it will have a focus rectangle surrounding the text part. I think this is a good UI feature and it could be problematic and confusing to some users if done otherwise.